# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) while writing data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, signals

then and now I am getting this error message, when I wrote data in the database over a longer period:

> 08-17 15:45:47.220: A/libc(10676): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000003b2 (code=0), thread 10676 (mb.bat)

I already found out, that this comes up, whenever android thinks, that the ui is frozen or, to be spezific, when ever somethings blocks the ui thread.

But here is, what i am wondering about:
The writing and everything is started by my own service, which SHOULD run in the background, independent from the main thread. Right?
To work with the sqlitehelper i need the context, which i am getting from the service, by simply calling

> getApplicationContext()

Is there something wrong with that?

Also:
The Service is restartet after the fatal signal, although I am not sure, whether this could be triggered by my own code, I did not find anything related to that though.

Comment: Try to pass the context from main or any other activity to service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services in android **do not** run in a separate thread form UI thread, like the activities they run on Main thread too. You should either define you one Thread and run it you make you of `IntentService` instead. But be careful that once the intentservice job is done it will sotp its self.

Check these out:
[link 1](http://www.inteist.com/2014/05/android-intentservice-vs-service/)
[link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: but when I do this (replace Service with IntentService), I get to another problem, would it not be easier, to run the things of the service in an async task?

Comment: If you just inserting some data into the database, using thread is a simple solution. Just create an Thread, pass it an Runnable object, in `run` method of Runnable perform insertion. don't forget to start your thread!. good luck.

Comment: I get data from a bluetooth module and insert it into the database.
As I do this also automatically every hour, I would like to keep the service. So just having a class, which extends from service and then executes the thread would be fine?

Comment: You should use a `Service` if you want to work with Bluetooth. and also you can create a thread in your service to run connection and fetching data in a different thread. (As I said before, service runs in the MainThread unless you make separate thread for your tasks).

Comment: Okay, I will try to just run the Service in a Thread, the Bluetooth Part is already running from its own threads, it is basically the bluetooth chat example by google.